# Android Oreo launcher icon set to default instead of custom

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Like in the title, Only on `Oreo` , application has wrong launcher icon.

All required sizes are in `mipmap`

[image: Directory hierarchy:]

I don't have -v26 and i just created virtual device (480x800 with Oreo) and still the result is wrong app icon (default: google android instead expected).

In androidmanifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a default `adaptive-icon`?

Comment: No, i don't have adaptive-icon

Comment: What's the expected result? What's the actual result? Screenshots please. Show us the file hierarchy, some people put drawables in wrong directory. Is there a `*-v26` directory?

Comment: This looks ok, can you post the `<application>` element from your manifest as well?